# How to display a short test report/counters in travis-ci?

Tags: testing, karma-runner, travis-ci

I mean, it would be very useful if I can see how many tests passed/failed just by one line, without reading build logs.

I use karma as test runner. It have a lot of reporter, but which one should I use?

Example from TeamCity:
[image: TeamCity tests counter]

Comment: Does the dot or progress reported fullfil your needs ?

Comment: I want to see it on build history list if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a useful feature but the current user interface doesn't seem to support it.

You can file it as a feature request on Travis CI's GitHub page using the link below:

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues

Answer (score 0):

Although Travis CI doesn't have its own interface for counting the number of tests passed, they do work with CodeClimate, which has it's it's interface and metrics for test coverage. It shows overall test coverage for the whole project and coverage for each file. There's some more info on that [here](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/setting-up-test-coverage#how-we-display-test-coverage), though it looks like their free version allows local testing only.

There are other tools out there for tracking and analyzing coverage as well, including [Coveralls](https://coveralls.io/features), which is pretty good as well. They have a free version for open source, like Travis CI, so that's can be a plus. They also show coverage as a percent and file-by-file.